# Is there a gui interface in moviepy to select the start and end time from video to trim it from webpage django

Tags: django, python-3.x, moviepy, django-2.2

i want a user to select the start and end using some gui in django
! https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDC4E.png (something like this)

For the time being the below mentioned code is what im doing. But it is not user friendly

video.html

```html
<video controls>
  <source src="{{ url }}" type="video/mp4"></source>
</video>

<div class="row">
    <form class="col s12" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input name="start_time" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="start_time">Start Time</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input name="end_time" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="end_time">End Time</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Start" class="btn">
    </form>
</div>
```

view.py

```py
if request.method == 'POST':
        start_time = int(request.POST.get('start_time'))
        end_time = int(request.POST.get('end_time'))
        path = "C:/Users/Macklon/Desktop/summer/cctv_modified/media/"
        clip = VideoFileClip(path+video).subclip(start_time, end_time)
        time = datetime.now().strftime("%H.%M.%S")
        print(clip.to_videofile(path+time+".mp4"))
        return render(request, "stream/video_list.html", {"url":video_url,"video_name":video_name})
```